# Does a software CPU analyzer for Windows Embedded Compact exist?

Tags: c++, c, windows, performance, windows-ce

Looking for a software logic analyzer for embedded Windows software that lets you visualize and troubleshoot complex target activities. Allows you to see, on a timeline, how tasks, OS, and interrupts interact - who has the CPU, what states are the different tasks in, are my timing requirements met, etc.

Does a software CPU analyzer for Windows Embedded Compact exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kernel Tracker to perform this kind of analysis. You can collect data by enabling celog and the use the tool to visualize the information.
Here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee479601.aspx
you can find some documentation about it in Compact2013 (I'm sorry but it seems that documentation for CE6 and Compact 7 has been hidden so well that even google can't find it!).